# Easy noob custom PHP question in views... Editing recent news stories view

Tags: views, entities

```
<?php
$href = $data->node_data_field_news_external_link_field_news_external_link_value;
if($href == ''){
    $href = 'node/' . $data->nid;
    $href = url($href, array('absolute' => TRUE));
}
echo '<h3><a href="' . $href . '">' . $data->node_title . ' (' . date("F j, Y", $data->node_created) . ')</a></h3>';
?>
```

I'm sorry but I've searched for something that can help me with this.  I know it is simple, but I've already spent hours while trying to teach myself PHP in the process.  I hope that this will take someone 30 secs and allow me to keep learning.

Anyways... I have an attribute (field_successdate) in the News content type that I'm trying to use.  It's a date of when the News happened.  In the view, the customPHP field uses the node's created date and appends it to the node's title to create a link to the object.  I'm trying to replace the node's created date with my field_successdate.  I've added it to the fields and then referencing it in the customPHP code, but no luck.  Do I have to add the field_successdate to the fields in the view and then add an argument? (I've tried that too)

Can any one help?

Thanks!!!

Comment: If anyone could show me how to do this in PHP just for the sake of learning, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easier to add the field to the field list (`field_successdate`). Then use Views `rewrite` display option to write the `node: title` link to include the date from `field_successdate`.

The rewrite will require the Token module to be enabled. rewrite the title as: `[node:title] [node:field_successdate]`

Be sure you hide `field_successdate` if you dont want it literally shown in the view by itself somewhere. You may or may not need to move `field_successdate` to the top of the field list so its gets made into a Token to be used in the title properly.

I'd make a pic of this .... but that'd take like minutes....

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. This is close... I'm able to get the result I want cosmetically, but now I can't get it to link to the individual node.  I've tried rewriting as a link and using a token to get to the link... but it links to the view, not the unique node...

Comment: Actually, I think I fixed it.  Thanks! I didn't think of using tokens!!!